# Add epsacrop to programmatically added image field

Tags: media

I'm adding an image field to my theme form in order to setup a default image for the user.
I'd like the user to be able to use [EPSAcrop](https://www.drupal.org/project/epsacrop) to crop the image he uploads here.

Is this possible, if so; How?

This is what I have now:

```
function MYTHEME_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id = NULL)  {
  $form['header_images'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Header image'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#description' => t('The default header image on every page. Unless a header image is selected in the node of the page.'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('header_images', ''),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://header_images/',
    '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('png, jpg, gif')),
  );
}
```

Comment: I think you should try [EPSA Crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/epsacrop) module. And if you want to crop the image with given dimension then you can try this function: image_scale_and_crop(stdClass $image, $width, $height)

Comment: Well yes. Epsacrop is the module I was talking about. Unless there are other EPSA crops out there? It still doesn't answer the question how I can hook up EPSAcrop to the field I created.

Comment: I also write there function name for the static dimensions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you change managed_file to media, you will have availability to manage EPSA cropping for the form image.